# Command line python is different from Python IDLE

Tags: command-line, python, idle-python

I have installed sklearn on Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I execute a script via the command line which imports sklearn, I get an import error. Running the same script with Python IDLE yields no error and executes the script. How can I make sure that my "command line python" uses the same version as IDLE? Apparantly, that one knows where to find my downloaded modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I added an alias to ~/.bashrc as follows:

```
    alias python=/usr/local/python
```

I found the path I was looking for by going to Python IDLE and doing the following:

```
    import sys
    sys.path
```

This returned the location of the python version IDLE uses. I searched around a bit and found the path I was looking for!